# Updating icon in real tme in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a favourites icon that should change from an outline to solid but it will only do this once the page has been reloaded. 
Is there any way to update this in real time without reloading the page.

It should update the `ng-class` to change from an outline to solid.

```
<i ng-class="{'icon ion-android-star': favicon(office.id), 'icon ion-android-star-outline': !favicon(office.id)}" 
    ng-click="togglefav(office.id); $event.stopPropagation();"></i>
```

This checks if the value is in local storage, then returns true or false.

```
.controller('APICtrl', function($scope, $http, $localstorage, $window, $state, $sce) {
// Search function
  $scope.query = {}
  $scope.queryBy = '$'
// gets the data from offices.json
 $http.get('js/offices.json').then(function(resp) {
    console.log('Success', resp);
    $scope.offices = resp.data.office;  
  }, function(err) {
    console.error('ERR', err);
    // err.status will contain the status code
  });

 $scope.sce = function(loc1){
 return $sce.trustAsHtml("https://www.google.com/maps/geocoding/json?address=loc1&key=AIzaSyBGAHnplGPjFoVvShk6Tsna3-DN8rHQBI8")
 }

//retrieves localstorage array
//$scope.favourties= JSON.parse($window.localStorage['fav']);
//$scope.favourites = $window.localStorage['favs'] ? JSON.parse($window.localStorage['favs']) : []
//checks if the array if is in localstorage, if it isnt then it adds an array, if it is it parses the array
if($window.localStorage['fav']){
    $scope.favorites = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['fav']);
    var fav = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['fav']);
} else {
    var fav = [];
    $window.localStorage['fav'] = JSON.stringify(fav);
}

console.log(fav);
$scope.togglefav = function(id) {
//checks if the id being passed in is already in the array
//if it isn't it will add it to the beginning array then stringify it
  if (fav.indexOf(id) == -1){
    fav.unshift(id);
    console.log(fav);
    $window.localStorage['fav'] = JSON.stringify(fav);
    }
//if it is then it will remove it from the array and stringify the array
    else{
      fav.splice(fav.indexOf(id), 1);
      $window.localStorage['fav'] = JSON.stringify(fav);
      console.log(fav);
    }
}

//last viewed office view
if($window.localStorage['last']){
    $scope.favorites = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['last']);
    var last = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['last']);
} else {
    var last = [];
    $window.localStorage['last'] = JSON.stringify(last);
}
console.log(last);
$scope.lastview = function(id) {
//checks if the id being passed in is already in the array
//if it isn't it will add it to the beginning array then stringify it
var c = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['last']);
  if (last.indexOf(id) == -1){
    if (c.length > 3){
      last.pop();
      }
    last.unshift(id);
    $window.localStorage['last'] = JSON.stringify(last);
    }
}


// used to change the favourites icon based on if its in the local storage or not
var e = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['fav']);
$scope.favicon = function(office){
return  e.indexOf(office) !== -1;
};

// used to check if the item is in localstorage and check it against the json array
// if it matches then it will return true and be displayed
// this one is used for favourited offices
$scope.ifinfav1 = function(office){
  return e.indexOf(office.id) !== -1;
};

var f = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['last']);

// this one is used for last viewed offices
$scope.ifinfav2 = function(office){
  return f.indexOf(office.id) !== -1;
};
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('includeExample', ['ngAnimate'])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$q',
      function($scope, $q) {

        $scope.office = {
          id: 'here'
        };
        //var e = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['fav']);
        var e = ['here']
        $scope.favicon = function(office) {
          return e.indexOf(office) !== -1;
        };

        $scope.togglefav = function(office) {
          if ($scope.office.id === 'here')
            $scope.office.id = 'here2';
          else
            $scope.office.id = 'here';
        };


      }
    ]);
})(window.angular);
```

```css
.ion-android-star{
 color:red;  
}
.ion-android-star-outline{
 color:blue;  
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-animate.js"></script>

<body ng-app="includeExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <i ng-class="{'icon ion-android-star': favicon(office.id), 'icon ion-android-star-outline': !favicon(office.id)}" ng-click="togglefav(office.id); "> Content</i> (click me)

  </div>
</body>
```

you can use the `$scope` in **office** variable.

when you change the office will be visible to the template as well.

Comment: can you post your controller? or add a jsfiddle?

Comment: I've added the controller but its quite a large one as it does a lot.

Comment: @Snow just posted a simple snippet on how you could do this change

Comment: I need to use the local storage to determine if the icon should change though which is what the original code does but it will only update the icon when the page is refreshed